# Why does supressing weights improve Tensorflow neural net performance?

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow

I have a 2-layer non-convolutional network in Tensorflow, using `tanh` as the activation function. I understand that weights should be initialized with a truncated normal distribution divided by `sqrt(nInputs)` e.g.:

```
weightsLayer1 = tf.Variable(tf.div(tf.truncated_normal([nInputUnits, nUnitsHiddenLayer1),math.sqrt(nInputUnits))))
```

Being a bit of a bumbling newbie in NN and Tensorflow, I mistakenly implemented this as 2 lines only to make it more readable:

```
weightsLayer1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([nInputUnits, nUnitsHiddenLayer1])
weightsLayer1 = tf.div(weightsLayer1, math.sqrt(nInputUnits))
```

I now know that this is wrong and that the 2nd line causes the weights to be recomputed at each learning step. However, to my suprise, the "incorrect" implementation consistently yields better performance, both in train and test/evaluation datasets. I thought that the incorrect 2-line implementation should be a train wreck, since it is recomputing (suppressing) weights to values other than those chosen by the optimizer, which I would expect would wreak havoc in the optimization process, but it actually improves it. Does anyone have any explanation for this? I am using the Tensorflow adam optimizer.

*Update 2016.6.22* - updated the 2nd code block above.

Comment: First of all: in the two-line implementation, you do the division by ``sqrt(nInputUnits)`` twice, effectively dividing by ``nInputUnits``. Is that intentional? Second: I don't exactly understand your question? Are you concerned that the variable ``weightsLayer1`` is re-initialized everytime it you run a training step? If so, that is not the case. I can elaborate on this, but I am not entirely sure if that is what you are actually asking about.

Comment: My mistake, the 2-line case above was entered here wrong, I've corrected it above. I divide by `sqrt(nInputUnits)` only once. In the 2-line case, I know that `weightsLayer1` is initialized only once in the `tf.Variable` line. My questions: a) Is it true that the second line (`weightsLayer1 = tf.div(weightsLayer1, math.sqrt(nInputUnits))`) executes at run time? b) If so, does it modify the value of `weightsLayer1` computed by the optimizer and therefore interfere with the optimization process? c) If so, how can this do better than the `weightsLayer1` values computed by the optimizer?

Comment: Okay, I think I got it now. See my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right that `weightsLayer1 = tf.div(weightsLayer1, math.sqrt(nInputUnits))` is executed at each step. But that does NOT mean that the values in the weight variable are scaled down by `sqrt(nInputUnits)` in each step. This line is not an in-place operation that affects the values stored in the variable. It computes a new tensor, holding the values in the variable divided by `sqrt(nInputUnits)` and that tensor, I assume, then goes into the rest of your computation graph. This does not interfere with the optimizer. You are still defining a valid computation graph, just with an somewhat arbitrary scaling of the weights. The optimizer can still compute the gradients with respect to this variable (it will back-propagate through your division operation) and create the corresponding update operations.

In terms of the model that you are defining, the two versions are totally equivalent. For any set of values of `weightsLayer1` in the original model (where you don't do the division), you can simply scale them up by `sqrt(nInputUnits)` and you will get the identical results with your second model. The two represent exactly the same model class, if you will.

Why one works better than the other? Your guess is as good as mine. If you have done the same division for all your variables, you have effectively divided your learning rate by `sqrt(nInputUnits)`. This smaller learning rate might have been beneficial to the problem at hand.

Edit: I think the fact that you give the same name to the variable and the newly created tensor causes confusion. When you do

```
A = tf.Variable(1.0)
A = tf.mul(A, 2.0)
# Do something with A
```

then the second line creates a new tensor (as discussed above) and you re-bind the name (and it is only a name) `A` to that new tensor. For the graph being defined, the naming is absolutely irrelevant. The following code defines the same graph:

```
A = tf.Variable(1.0)
B = tf.mul(A, 2.0)
# Do something with B
```

Maybe this becomes clear if you execute the following code:

```
A = tf.Variable(1.0)
print A
B = A
A = tf.mul(A, 2.0)
print A
print B
```

The output is

```
<tensorflow.python.ops.variables.Variable object at 0x7ff025c02bd0>
Tensor("Mul:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)
<tensorflow.python.ops.variables.Variable object at 0x7ff025c02bd0>
```

The first time you `print A` it tells you that `A` is a variable object. After executing `A = tf.mul(A, 2.0)` and printing `A` again, you can see that the name `A` is now bound to a `tf.Tensor` object. However, the variable still exists, as can be seen by looking at the object behind the name `B`.

Comment: Thanks. So if I do `A = tf.Variable(1.0)` and then `A = tf.mul(A, 2.0)` the second line does not modify A but rather creates another tensor, also named A, and Tensorflow knows to use the second A rather than the first when A is used elsewhere in the computation graph? I suppose this is functionally equivalant to modifying the value in the variable A, yes?

Answer (score 1):

This is what the single line of code does:

```
t = tf.truncated_normal( [ nInputUnits, nUnitsHiddenLayer1 ] )
```

Creates a [`Tensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/constant_op.html#truncated_normal) with shape [ nInputUnits, nUnitsHiddenLayer1 ], initialized with 1.0 as the standard deviation of the truncated normal distribution. ( 1.0 is standard stddev value )

```
t1 = tf.div( t, math.sqrt( nInputUnits ) )
```

[divide](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/math_ops.html#div) all values in t with math.sqrt( nInputUnits )

Your two lines of code do exactly the same thing. On the first line and the second line all values are divided by math.sqrt( nInputUnits ).

As for your statement:

> I now know that this is wrong and that the 2nd line causes the weights to be recomputed at each learning step.

**EDIT my mistake**

Indeed you are right, they are divided by math.sqrt( nInputUnits ) at every execuction, but not reinitialized! The point of importance is where you put `tf.variable()`

Here both lines are only initialized once:

```
weightsLayer1 = tf.truncated_normal( [ nInputUnits, nUnitsHiddenLayer1 ] )
weightsLayer1 = tf.Variable( tf.div( weightsLayer1, math.sqrt( nInputUnits ) ) )
```

and here the second line is preformed at every step:

```
weightsLayer1 = tf.Variable( tf.truncated_normal( [ nInputUnits, nUnitsHiddenLayer1 ] )
weightsLayer1 = tf.div( weightsLayer1, math.sqrt( nInputUnits ) )
```

Why does the second yield better results? it looks like some kind normalization to me, but somebody more knowledgeable should verify that.

Ps.
you can write it more readable like this:

```
weightsLayer1 = tf.Variable( tf.truncated_normal( [ nInputUnits, nUnitsHiddenLayer1 ] , stddev = 1. / math.sqrt( nInputUnits ) )
```

Comment: My understanding is that e.g. `Y = tf.Variable(2.0)` is an initalization that runs only once while `Y = tf.div(Y, X)` runs at each execution step of the graph. Is that correct? If so then yes I am initializing things once but it would seem that the second line would run at each step and change the weights values to other than those computed by the optimizer.